# Why does the compiler give an ambiguous invocation error when passing inherited types?

Tags: c#

What is happening in the C# compiler to cause the following ambiguous invocation compilation error?

The same issue applies to extension methods, or when `TestClass` is generic and using instance rather than static methods.

I realise it is rather easy to resolve (e.g. cast `secondInstance` to `Test1` on the method call) but I'm more curious what logic is being applied by the compiler for method selection.

My assumption is that the compiler applies some level of specificity measure (like CSS) on method detection to determine the most specific match - is this invalid?

```
class Type1 { }
class Type2 : Type1 {}

class TestClass
{
    public static void Do<T>(T something, object o) where T : Type1
    {} 

    public static void Do(Type1 something, string o)
    {}
}

void Main()
{
    var firstInstance = new Type1();
    TestClass.Do(firstInstance, new object()); // Calls Do<T>(T, obj)
    TestClass.Do(firstInstance, "Test"); // Calls Do(Type1, string)

    var secondInstance = new Type2();
    TestClass.Do(secondInstance, new object()); // Calls Do<T>(T, obj)
    TestClass.Do(secondInstance, "Test"); // "The call is ambiguous" compile error
}
```

// Edit: mike z proposed a concept I've interpreted as a "cast distance" is being used as a weight for method selection. A test for this seems to support that (although I'm not sure how Type->Generic Type is weighted).

```
// Add the following two methods to TestClass
public static void Do<T>(T something) where T : Type1
{} 

public static void Do(Type1 something)
{}

public static void Do<T>(T something, object o) where T : Type1
{} 

public static void Do(Type1 something, string o)
{}

void Main()
{
    var firstInstance = new Type1();

    // Can't select string
    TestClass.Do(firstInstance, new object()); // Calls Do<T>(T, obj)

    // Do() distance is 0, Do<T> distance is 1
    TestClass.Do(firstInstance, "Test"); // Calls Do(Type1, string)

    // Do() distance is 0, Do<T> distance is ? (but more than 0?)
    TestClass.Do(firstInstance); // Calls Do(Type1)

    var secondInstance = new Type2();

    // Can't select string
    TestClass.Do(secondInstance, new object()); // Calls Do<T>(T, obj)

    // Do() distance is 1, Do<T> distance is 1
    TestClass.Do(secondInstance, "Test"); // "The call is ambiguous" compile error

    // Do() distance is 1, Do<T> distance is ? (but less than 1?)
    TestClass.Do(secondInstance); // Calls Do<T>(T)

}
```

Comment: It doesn't know which 'Do' to chose because string is also an object.  You could switch your parameter order, or be more explicit on the call 'Do<Type1>'

Comment: It manages to determine that a `string` is more specific than `object` when the first parameter is explicitly a `Type1`, but not when the first parameter inherits from `Type1`

Comment: I would really try to avoid that situation. You can prevent a lot of confusion if you don't name generic methods the same as non generic ones. Same goes for classes btw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overload resolution is covered in section 7.5.3. It is complicated, but the basic idea is that compiler will determine the "best" overload based on the number and kind of conversions it needs to do.

For case 1, there is an exact type match on the generic overload.
For case 2, there is an exact type match on the non-generic overload.
For case 3, the generic overload is an exact match. Note: your comment is incorrect. The type of `T` will be `Type2`.
For case 4, the generic overload requires a conversion from string to object while the non-generic method requires a conversion from `Type2` to `Type1`. Note these are both reference conversions to a base type. Since one of the same kind of conversion is required in both cases, the compiler refuses to decide for you and gives you an error that the call is ambiguous. There is no "best" match.

Comment: Updated incorrect comments thanks. I think you're on the mark. I'm not sure how generic "casting/selection" is weighted though. I've added an updated sample testing your theory.

Comment: @MattMitchell I'm not so sure I would call it a "distance" but it is something like that. Note that an overload that has the exact matching parameter types is always considered better than an otherwise equivalent overload with generic parameters, as some of your later examples show.